# Get Hours From 2 Overlapping Datetime Ranges

Tags: php, mysql

I want to determine how to get the hours from 2 overlapping datetime ranges. For example using table below:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `schedules` (
      `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `start1` datetime NOT NULL,
      `end1` datetime NOT NULL,
      `start2` datetime NOT NULL,
      `end2` datetime NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=37;



    INSERT INTO `schedules` (`id`, `start1`, `end1`, `start2`, `end2`) VALUES
        (1, '2017-04-16T14:00:00', '2017-04-16T23:00:00', '2017-04-16T22:00:00', '2017-04-17T06:00:00'),
        (2, '2017-04-17T17:00:00', '2017-04-18T02:00:00', '2017-04-17T22:00:00', '2017-04-18T06:00:00'),
        (3, '2017-04-18T15:00:00', '2017-04-19T01:00:00', '2017-04-18T22:00:00', '2017-04-19T06:00:00')
        (4, '2017-04-19T22:00:00', '2017-04-20T06:00:00', '2017-04-19T22:00:00', '2017-04-20T06:00:00'),
        (5, '2017-04-20T23:00:00', '2017-04-21T08:00:00', '2017-04-20T22:00:00', '2017-04-21T06:00:00');
```

The result should be should be:

```
   id, Hours
    1,   1
    2,   4
    3,   3
    4,   8
    5,   7
```

I previously got a way using multiple IF statement but I think its running slow. I'll gladly appreciate if you can give me a simple and faster query.

Comment: Why are there two starts and ends? Shouldn't these be separate rows?

Comment: No, I am saving 2 date ranges in same row. Its easier for me to determine for massive records.

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: @Strawberry I added the 2nd date range because it differs for every row.

Comment: There is possible  that date ranges not overlapping each other at all ?

Comment: @OtoShavadze Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you said `I previously got a way using multiple IF statement`, and this solution looks like it, but anyway, just try, may be better ?

```
select `schedules`.*, 
CASE 
    WHEN `end2` <=  `start1` OR `start2` >= `end1` THEN  NULL -- not overlaps at all
    WHEN `start2` <= `start1` AND `end2` <= `end1` THEN  TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, `start1`, `end2`)  
    WHEN `start2` <= `start1` AND `end2` > `end1`  THEN  TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, `start1`, `end1`)
    WHEN `start2` > `start1` AND `end2` <= `end1`  THEN  TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, `start2`, `end2`)
    WHEN `start2` > `start1` AND `end2` > `end1`   THEN  TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, `start2`, `end1`)
END AS hourdiff
from `schedules`
```

Comment: Nice! This works, and it looks cleaner than my nested if statements. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's difference between between end1 and start2.

If so, try using `timediff` and `time_to_sec` for this:

```
select id, time_to_sec(timediff(end1, start2)) / 3600 from schedules;
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/LIWKKK17869)

Comment: Yes, but there is a different scenario like start1 > star2 and end1 > end2 or like start1=start2 and end1=end2,  etc.

Comment: @Nico - Please add sample data for those scenarios too and explain clearly what you'd like to do in that case.

Comment: Sure thing, I added more data for different scenario.